# Vague syntax error on an SQL query in Maria-DB

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
INSERT INTO "order" SET `user_id` = 5, `week_id` = 1, `box_settings_id` = '1', `delivery_day` = 'Thursday', `delivery_time` = 'Morning 6am - 9am', `notes` = '', `recipes` = '70, 71, 72, 74';
```

What is wrong with my SQL query? I'm getting this error in PHPMyAdmin:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '"order" SET `user_id` = 5, `week_id` = 1, `box_settings_id` = '1', `delivery_day' at line 1
```

While the SQL debugger isn't showing any error.

Comment: @forpas okay so I'm using this `INSERT INTO person SET first_name = 'John', last_name = 'Doe';`, am I doing anything incorrectly?

Comment: forpas supposed you were mixing insert and update syntax mistakenly. I had never seen this non-standard syntax you are using either. I had to look it up, which forpas obviously did, too :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner forpas is a mean person that I completely ignored after his last comment and he eventually deleted *sigh*. People are unnecessarily mean here. :(

Comment: Sometimes we are by mistake. When I saw your request, I was absolutely sure that your syntax was wrong. And then I saw forpas deleting their comment, which made me look this syntax up. Yep, it would have been much better had they said "Sorry, I was mistaken". I agree. forpas has written many good answers, though, and helped loads of people. Sometimes with mere comments. And sometimes we sound a bit harsh, but we are really here to help.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I don't honestly mind, words never hurt me personally, I just mind those who quickly jump to "-1". All good. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue likely is due to use of double quotes which MySQL and MariaDB diverge from the ANSI SQL standard. Instead of double quotes (synonymous to single quotes for string literals), MariaDB and MySQL would use backticks. With that said, you can adjust [SQL mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) to non-default `ANSI` or `ANSI_QUOTES` to support double quotes for identifiers:

> **ANSI_QUOTES**
> Changes `"` to be treated as `, the identifier quote character. This may break old MariaDB applications which assume that " is used as a string quote character.

Therefore, simply use backticks on `order` table like you do for columns. Generally, any identifier can use backticks.

```
INSERT INTO `order` 
SET `user_id` = 5, 
    `week_id` = 1, 
    `box_settings_id` = '1', 
    `delivery_day` = 'Thursday', 
    `delivery_time` = 'Morning 6am - 9am', 
    `notes` = '', 
    `recipes` = '70, 71, 72, 74';
```

Comment: Or even better, remove the double quotes and backticks altogether. They are not needed here. ;-)

Comment: I didn't know about this. I'm using this in node.js, I'll research how I can escape the backticks. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, `order` is a reserved word in [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner They somehow are, "order" is a reserved keyword.